# How to publish a config into parent component when the child component has ViewModel in extjs

Tags: extjs, mvvm, bind

I have an extjs class which has a *config* field and now I want to *publish* its changes to the parent container.

It is ok when I have no *viewModel* in child component but whenever I add a viewModel to the child class it breaks! and it is because of publishing. It publishes its data to the closest ViewModel!

How can I achieve this?
Check the fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hj2
in the fiddle if you uncomment the commented line , you will see that changing the field doesn't publish into the window header.

Comment: As you have parent container and child item in it, it's better to define to models and create one-to-one references. However, I'm not 100% how it shall look like.

Comment: I dont get your point by one-to-one references. btw, my child component may has a viewmodel by itself and I cannot move it to somewhere else (because of some formulas it uses)

Comment: As in documents mentioned, *publishes* value must be declare as object for classes.

Comment: This is required for the config system to properly merge values from derived classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn't find a prefect way. the only solution I found is :
1- getting child's ViewModel
2- calling **bind** function on the child's VM to get the changes and putting the value into the desired place :

vm.bind('{a.c}',function(v){w.setTitle(v)});

check this fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hrp

Answer (score 1):

Try the `Bindable` override from here

https://github.com/alexeysolonets/extjs-mvvm-extensions

It was made right for the purpose of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The [viewModel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-viewModel) Defaults to: {$value: null, lazy: true}, passing '{}' configuration might be the issue

```
viewModel:{$value: null}, //works
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help at all cases. If I set $value(which is a private field!)  to null, it causes the viewModel to be null.